# Read values out of PetscEventPerfInfo

Tags: petsc

I have an application using PETSc. For performance monitoring under (near) production runs, I'd like to log a small number of various values. Some generated by PETSc, some not.

Now I wonder: How can I read the time value out of `PetscEventPerfInfo` to write it into my file? I can't find a documentation entry about `PetscEventPerfInfo`, so I'm not sure whether I'm not supposed to touch it in any way.

However, I found the following method which basically reveals the structure of `PetscEventPerfInfo`:

```
PetscErrorCode EventPerfInfoClear(PetscEventPerfInfo *eventInfo)
{
  PetscFunctionBegin;
  eventInfo->id            = -1;
  eventInfo->active        = PETSC_TRUE;
  eventInfo->visible       = PETSC_TRUE;
  eventInfo->depth         = 0;
  eventInfo->count         = 0;
  eventInfo->flops         = 0.0;
  eventInfo->flops2        = 0.0;
  eventInfo->flopsTmp      = 0.0;
  eventInfo->time          = 0.0;
  eventInfo->time2         = 0.0;
  eventInfo->timeTmp       = 0.0;
  eventInfo->numMessages   = 0.0;
  eventInfo->messageLength = 0.0;
  eventInfo->numReductions = 0.0;
  PetscFunctionReturn(0);
}
```

I have a strong guess that it's just `eventInfo->time`, but I'm absolutely not sure whether it's save to read it oder whether there's an "official" way to read from that structure.

**So, what should I do if I just want to read the time value into a variable for further usage?**

Answer (score 1):

**Good news: there is an example of PETSC,  [src/dm/impls/plex/examples/tests/ex9.c](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/src/dm/impls/plex/examples/tests/ex9.c.html) which makes use of the field `time` of `PetscEventPerfInfo` to print performance-related logs!**

The structure `PetscEventPerfInfo` is defined in [`petsc-3.7.6/include/petsclog.h`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/include/petsclog.h.html). 
There are plenty of comments in the file.
The field `time` is indeed defined as:

```
PetscLogDouble time, time2, timeTmp;   /* The time and time^2 taken for this event */
```

There are clues that `time` contains the execution time in [`eventlog.c`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/src/sys/logging/utils/eventlog.c.html#PetscLogEventBeginComplete). Indeed, in function `PetscLogEventBeginComplete`, there is a `eventPerfLog->eventInfo[event].time -= curTime;`, which matches the `eventPerfLog->eventInfo[event].time += curTime;` of `PetscLogEventEndComplete()`.

Consequently, the value of the field `time` is interesting if an only if both `PetscLogEventBeginComplete()` and `PetscLogEventEndComplete()` have been called or both `PetscLogEventBeginDefault()` and `PetscLogEventEndDefault()`.